# Android. Generated sine wave produces knock noise every second

Tags: android, audio, wave, trigonometry

I want to generate sine wave with combined frequencies. I'm going this way:

```
public static byte[] combineSineWave(Collection<Double> frequencies) {
    double[] sample = new double[SAMPLE_RATE];
    byte[] result = new byte[2 * SAMPLE_RATE];

    double coefficient = 2 * Math.PI;

    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE; i++) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (double frequency : frequencies) {
            sum += Math.sin(coefficient * i * frequency / SAMPLE_RATE);
        }

        sample[i] = sum / frequencies.size();
    }

    convertToPCM16Bit(sample, result);

    return result;
}

private static void convertToPCM16Bit(double[] sample, byte[] result) {
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        result[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        result[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }
}
```

And playing generated bytes by this code:

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SoundWaveGenerator.SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 2 * SoundWaveGenerator.SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    audioTrack.play();

    while (true) {
        byte[] bytes = SoundWaveGenerator.combineSineWave(frequencies);
        audioTrack.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
```

But the problem is that I hear a click about every second. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click you are hearing is the discontinuity between each call to combineSineWave. In each call to combineSineWave each frequency will start out a zero degrees of phase. But, depending on the frequency, may not produce an even number of cycles by the end of the 1 second interval. Say one of the frequencies is such that the last sample of the second is at 90 deg (1.0) then there is a discontinuity when you generate the next interval.

To solve this, you need to keep track of some state between successive calls. I've coded an example below, but I don't know how to pass by reference in Java. Also, you'll need to deal with the possibility of i rolling over.

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    byte[] bytes = SoundWaveGenerator.combineSineWave(frequencies, ref i);
    audioTrack.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}


public static byte[] combineSineWave(Collection<Double> frequencies, ref int i) {
    double[] sample = new double[SAMPLE_RATE];
    byte[] result = new byte[2 * SAMPLE_RATE];

    double coefficient = 2 * Math.PI;

    for (int j = 0; j < SAMPLE_RATE; j++) {
        double sum = 0;

        for (double frequency : frequencies) {
            sum += Math.sin(coefficient * i++ * frequency / SAMPLE_RATE);
        }
        sample[i] = sum / frequencies.size();
    }

    convertToPCM16Bit(sample, result);

    return result;
}
```

P.S. you can divide by `SAMPLE_RATE` outside of the loop.

```
double coefficient = 2 * Math.PI / SAMPLE_RATE;
```

Comment: ok, so I should "continue" wave. But in this case I will get `i` index overflow. Also I see that in your code `saple[0] == sample[SAMPLE_RATE + 1]` and then the problem is still there, right? Is it possible to calculare correct length for sound where I will have even number of cycles? I thought that 2 * Math.PI correct period of the sine wave, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to precompute a length where you'd have an even number of cycles. Imagine a sine wave at 1kHz combined with a sine wave of 1.00001kHz.

Comment: so the solution is that we can only put aside "click" noise.  We can hear it not every 1 second but, we will hear it every 1 hour (for example). Is it true?

Comment: No, there is a better solution but it requires a bit of refactoring. Instead of passing the frequencies in, you precompute the phase increment, pass that along and then you need to keep track of the current phase of each tone. This is allowed to wrap around because the phase counter is scaled between 0 and 2*pi. I'll update my answer as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: wrote some code http://pastebin.com/KwRZ0jZy with this example http://basicsynth.com/index.php?page=basic&WEBMGR=...3bf4c0509ba3e1b29dc79b64a and with your help. And it works.